# Python to c# reduce function understanding

Tags: c#, python, reduce

I am struggling to understand the 'reduce' call written below in python.

I have found several sources, both here and elsewhere, that state what the function does, and that there's an equivalent 'aggregate' for lists in C#, but I am unable to understand what do the calls below actually -expect-... possibly because I can't really figure what does '_keep_left' returns?

So:

1- can anybody help telling me what does '_keep_left' return?

2- what does `, [])` mean in the reduce call?

Many thanks.

```
TURN_LEFT, TURN_RIGHT, TURN_NONE = (1, -1, 0)

def turn(p, q, r):
    """Returns -1, 0, 1 if p,q,r forms a right, straight, or left turn."""
    return cmp((q[0] - p[0])*(r[1] - p[1]) - (r[0] - p[0])*(q[1] - p[1]), 0)

def _keep_left(hull, r):
    while len(hull) > 1 and turn(hull[-2], hull[-1], r) != TURN_LEFT:
            hull.pop()
    return (not len(hull) or hull[-1] != r) and hull.append(r) or hull

def _graham_scan(points):
    """Returns points on convex hull of an array of points in CCW order."""
    points.sort()
    lh = reduce(_keep_left, points, [])
    uh = reduce(_keep_left, reversed(points), [])
    return lh.extend(uh[i] for i in xrange(1, len(uh) - 1)) or lh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `_keep_left` returns a list `hull`, which is initially empty. Turns not going left are removed from it. The current point is added into it, unless it is already the last element on the list.
2. `,  [])` is the third parameter to reduce. It is the initial accumulator value, which will be passed to `_keep_left`, thus making `hull` (and, in the end, `lh` and `uh`) initially empty.

It performs [Graham scan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) by first sorting the points, then going through all the points twice (`lh` and `uh` stand for lower half and upper half), and with each sweep the points are accumulated to the list. The points are accumulated with `reduce`, that is, the result is originally empty, and the points are passed to `_keep_left` one by one (in the sorted order), and for each point the points causing a right turn are removed from the accumulated list. Then the current point is added to the accumulated list.

The return value from `_keep_left` is a bit tricky: `not len(hull)` returns True if the list is empty. `hull[-1] != r` checks if `r` (the current point) is the last element in the list. `hull.append(r)` is in the boolean expression only for the side effect of appending `r` to the list (looks a bit dirty to me), so that if the last element of `hull` is `r`, `hull` will be returned without appending `r` to it.

Put in other words, due to short circuiting `hull` will always be returned, but `r` will be appended to it before returning it if it's not the last element. The same logic should be easy to implement in a nicer, yet more verbose, way.

Comment: Thanks for the extraordinarily clear explanation. I was tricked by the expectation that 'reduce' would return something meaningful for the iteration, while the true action happens thanks to the 'append' command in turn_left! hah!